# Angular $httpProvider transformResponse data contains local HTML DOM elements?

Tags: angularjs, service, httpresponse

When I instantiate the following code in an AngularJS app, I get weird data in the transformResponse function (bottom of code). I'm not calling the $resource function from any controller, just loading the script in a browser. The data variable (see code) contains *the HTML of the current partial*, when loading the app.

This seems odd. Is this the way it's supposed to be?

```
var buddyServices = angular
.module('buddyServices', ['ng','ngResource'])
.factory('Buddy',
    function ($resource) {    console.log('resource');
        return $resource('http://webservice.buddyplatform.com/v1/:service',
            {service:'', BuddyApplicationName: 'xxx',
            BuddyApplicationPassword: 'yyy'}
        );
    }
)
.config(function($httpProvider){
    delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
    $httpProvider.defaults.transformResponse = function(data) {   
        console.log(data);
        return 'TEST: '+data;
    };
});
```

=== EDIT ===

It just daunted on me: $httpProvider handles *all* http requests, so a page load is one of those. I'm guessing a bit now, but it seems probable. So, the question then becomes: Is there an "easy" way to constrain the data in the code above to only those requests performed by my service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`transformResponse` takes another parameter `headersGetter`. You can use this to get the headers send with the response. Look for `Content-Type` header header. It should contain `application/json`

Comment: I'm not after the headers, though. I'm after the response *data*. I would like to be able to pass it on as it is, in certain cases. And I only want this to happen when I call my function.

Comment: The header Content-type can be used to differentiate between html content, json content or xml content. If you service calls are returning json data or xml data, you can very well put a filter for content-type, because html partials are returned with content-type text/html